# pyspark: drop duplicates with exclusive subset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can use `df1.dropDuplicates(subset=["col1","col2"])` to drop all rows that are duplicates in terms of the columns defined in the subset list.

Is it possible to have the same result by specifying the columns not to include in the subset list (something like `df1.dropDuplicates(subset=~["col3","col4"])`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1.dropDuplicates(subset=[col for col in df1.columns if col not in ["col3","col4"]])
```